# linq-xml query for facebook likes

Tags: c#, linq, facebook-graph-api, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to get the total count of facebook likes for links. paste the link in your browser to see the xml response

Heres's what I'm doing:

```
var link = "https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20%20like_count,%20total_count,%20share_count,%20click_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url=%22http://micgadget.com/29723/the-undercover-report-on-how-the-new-iphone-5-is-made-inside-foxconn-factory/%22";
//var xml = MakeRequest(link);
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(link);

var likes = (from e in xdoc.Descendants("total_count")
             select e).SingleOrDefault().Value;
return int.Parse(likes);
```

It's throwing an object reference query  at the linq query.
How can i get the toal_count from the response?

Thanks

Comment: based on the url you give there is no number of likes

Comment: i want total_count - heres the link https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20%20like_count,%20total_count,%20share_count,%20click_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url=%22http://micgadget.com/29723/the-undercover-report-on-how-the-new-iphone-5-is-made-inside-foxconn-factory/%22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
var link = "https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20%20like_count,%20total_count,%20share_count,%20click_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url=%22http://micgadget.com/29723/the-undercover-report-on-how-the-new-iphone-5-is-made-inside-foxconn-factory/%22";
//var xml = MakeRequest(link);
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(link);

var query =  xdoc.Descendants().SingleOrDefault(o => o.Name.LocalName == "total_count");

if (!(query == null))
{
    int count = int.Parse(query.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all total_Count has no descendants, so you can not query that if you want the value of that element.
Second, the resulting XML elements include a namespace. You need to include these when searching the .value of that element. Try something like this

```
var link = "https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20%20like_count,%20total_count,%20share_count,%20click_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url=%22http://micgadget.com/29723/the-undercover-report-on-how-the-new-iphone-5-is-made-inside-foxconn-factory/%22";
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(link);
XNamespace ns = xdoc.Root.Attribute("xmlns").Value;

var likes = (from e in xdoc.Descendants() where e.Name == ns + "total_count"
             select e.Value).SingleOrDefault();
```